# All tests get terminated in Intellij with Spring Boot and JUnit5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I was trying to write a simple test in my Spring boot app with JUnit5 and I notice that all of my tests get instanly terminated. I downloaded some unit testing example and it worked just fine so I don't know what is wrong with my set up.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here's my example test that gets terminated:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class DemoClassTest {

    @Test
    void testOne() {

    }
}
```

And here's my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[Image from Intellij](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFfde.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean "gets terminated"? There's no content inside your test; it finishes instantly.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- It finishes with exit code -1 no matter what is the content of test method.

Comment: what happens when you run it with `mvn test` or `mvnw test` (from root directory)

Comment: First it says JAVA_HOME is not found in my environment. After I fixed this it says that build is successful and i ran 0 tests.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should remove `junit-jupiter-engine` and `mockito-junit-jupiter` dependencies as it is already included by `spring-boot-starter-test` which let SpringBoot handle incompatible versions issue between dependencies for you.

You might also want to remove the `junit-vintage-engine` exclusion to allow both Junit5 and Junit4 test execution